# Python 3: How to create a Dictionary with multiple dictionaries in it and where the keys also have multiple values?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, set, key-value, inventory

I've been writing a code for an Inventory-type system and all this time I've been using `set()` only to realize that strings/numbers inside it are not in order.

So I'll be rewriting my code again and will use `dict()` instead. However, i still have no idea how to take this approach. I'd like my output to be something like this:

`{'fruits':{'apple':{20, 15}},{'orange':{10, 12}}}, {'veggies':{'cucumber':{30, 20}}, {'cabbage':{40, 15}}}}`

Note: I'm not sure if it's brackets or braces i should use as examples

Simply put:

```
Fruits & Veggies - Inventory Names
Apple and Orange - Items in the Inventory
10, 30 & 40 - Number of stocks of the item
12, 20,& 15 - Amount of each item
```

My code:

https://pastebin.com/gu5DJX5K
*Been searching for a while now and can't find similar example of codes i can apply to mine.*

Comment: Dictionaries also not ordered (for Python versions < 3.7).  You may be interested in [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: Noted. will consider that. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are not ordered either - both sets and dictionaries in Python use hash tables, which do not preserve ordering. If you need ordering, you should use classes or lists.

If you use dictionaries anyway, it's perfectly fine for the values in a dictionary to be another dictionary. To have multiple values for a key, store the values in a list, and it the value corresponding to that key will be the list (or if you don't need ordering, a set).

It would look something like:

```
{"fruits" => {"apple" => [20, 15]
              "orange" => [10, 12]}
 "veggies" => {"cucumber" => [30, 20]
               "cabbage" => [40, 15]}}
```

However, I strongly discourage you from using dictionaries for everything. Classes are just much cleaner to use. I would recommend something along the lines of:

```
class Inventory:
    def __init__(self, fruits, veggies):
        self.fruits = fruits # list of Items
        self.veggies = veggies # another list of Items

class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, stock, amount):
        self.name = name # a string
        self.stock = stock # an int
        self.amount = amount # an int
```

Comment: I'm trying to picture it in my mind. Do you mean a set of lists inside a dictionary? or a set of lists in a list?

Comment: Which approach are you referring to, the first paragraph or second?

Comment: The second approach (I guess you can use an OrderedDict) is a structure like: (actually I'll include it in the answer)

Comment: The second one. Now that you updated your comment. I guess I'll give the 'class' a try. Should i make it a 'class' for items inside a 'class' for inventories?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "inside," but it should be two classes, Inventory and Item. One Inventory contains two lists of Items: one list of fruit, and one list of veggies.

Comment: i meant something like a nested class - if there's something like that. But i'm grateful for the idea. All i need is idea so i can move forward. Thank you so much.

Comment: i just noticed your second update, is that the orderdict or the class?

Comment: I added the dictionary method for clarification, but I would still recommend the class approach, in the last paragraph. There is no need for a nested class; Item is defined outside of Inventory. It's just that Inventory contains Items in its instance variables.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll go with the 'class' May you have a splendid day sir!